# Apache redirect some requests to another server

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

We just bought a new server.

We want our old server to respond the https connections(because of ssl certificate) and new server to respond the rest. New server is ready but i don't know how to redirect requests to new one.

```
mydomain.com => old machine ip
10.10.10.41 => new machine
```

Requests will come through mydomain.com.

```
If it is https:
   respond
else
   redirect to 10.10.10.41
```

How should i configure apache for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a seperate vhost for the https version of the domain, and use mod_proxy to proxy the request to your internal server. See  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass for examples.